# mysql IN with both params comma separated

Tags: mysql

I have rows in my db with a field "groups" of comma-separated IDs and I need to find the ones those have at least one id of another comma-separated value.

Example, rows in my DB:

```
ID | Groups

1  | 2,3
2  | 3
3  | 4
```

I need to find the rows with at least one of these groups: 5,3 (or maybe 3 without comma). So, for example in this case the IDs 1 and 2. The same result will be for "3" as group to find.

So, without explode 5,3 and do a foreach, is there a way with MySQL?

Comment: How many groups can one ID belong to? Only one or two or is there a limit? I do not want to complain that this is bad DB design ;)

Comment: Yes, it's a bad DB design of course. I agree. But it's an old structure and I can't change it. Anyway it's small, < 100

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a undefined number of comma-separated value in one column doesn't seem to be possible in MySQL.

If you would know that there is f. ex. max 3 items like "item1, item2, item3" you could do the following:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Groups, ',', 1) AS group1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Groups, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS group2,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Groups, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS group3
FROM tablename;
```

But that would mean that you know how many items you have.

I think and would recommend as the easiest/fastest way to split it in a language of your choice, i. e. PHP.